# How to make level.missed_days = habit.missed_days? [Gist Included]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, data-binding

I'm trying to gamify the forming of good habits.

When the user creates a new habit there are 5 levels before achieving "mastery"! Each level has a certain amount of days associated with it (shown in **habits.rb** `n_days`).

This is where I'm stuck: Despite checking the `missed_days` box for `:level` 1 in the `:habit` _form, the console showed `missed_days: 0` for `Habit.find(1)` yet `missed_days: 1` for `Level.find(1)`.

Missing a day is a bad thing because the idea is if you miss a day (represented by checking a box), a day is added back into your current_level (through the days_missed controller), in other words only completed days count toward completing a level.

How can we get it so that how ever many `:missed_days` are in `:level` will also be the same integer in `:habit`?

Habits `has_many` levels.

[image]

**habits _form**

```
  <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id"> Missed: </label>
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <p>
        <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id"> Level <%= index + 1 %>: </label>
        <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
        <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
        <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`habit-check` is in regards to **habit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
    level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
         method: "POST"
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
         method: "DELETE"
       });
    }
  });
});
```

This is what happens in the **terminal** when I click a checkbox:

```html
Started POST "/habits/2/levels/6/days_missed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 13:57:20 -0400
Processing by DaysMissedController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"habit_id"=>"2", "level_id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Habit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Habit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits"
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  Habit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Level Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = ? AND "levels"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["habit_id", 2], ["id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "levels" SET "missed_days" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "levels"."id" = ?  [["missed_days", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-04-28 17:57:20.960578"], ["id", 6]]
   (3.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
```

**habits.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

    attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
            actual_days = n_days - self.missed_days

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
        end
    end
end
```

**days_missed_controller.rb**

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

def create
  level = Habit.find(params[:habit_id]).levels.find(params[:level_id])
  level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
  level.save!
  head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
end

def destroy
  level = Habit.find(params[:habit_id]).levels.find(params[:level_id])
  level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
  level.save!
  head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :habits do
  resources :comments
  resources :levels do
    # we'll use this route to increment and decrement the missed days
    resources :days_missed, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Here's the gist of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to include all the relevant code in your question, rather than forcing us to go off-site to github to go look at it. Can you please edit your question and put the relevant sections there? (don't put any code in comments as the formatting is awful).

Comment: Hi thanks @TarynEast been here for a few months now. New to gists though so I thought it might be easier then me putting up a lot of code like I sometimes do especially for a question like this that can be cost by a whole host of issues. In the future though I'll be sure to add more code in the start.

Comment: Yeah no probs - it's true we don't want to be inundated with *all* the code either... keeping the lot in a gist is great and even pointing to it... but if you put the relevant stuff here, then it means we can look right at the problem without going anywhere else - also means that if the gist goes away (links go stale)... the question is still complete :)

Comment: Your checkbox tags... don't seem to have any kind of name or id attached to them. When you look at the resulting html - what shows up? Also: what shows up in the params that come through to your habit-controller (look in server logs for that) also: can you explain a bit better: a) what is the expected functionality and b) what you are seeing instead (your explanation is missing some information because I am still confused about what you are trying to do). Perhaps give a step-by-step of proper usage of the checkboxes and expected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast for the guidance! Hopefully I clarified myself better now that the question is longer, hopefully not too long by putting you to sleep. Please let me know if I can answer any of your questions better :)

Comment: `{"habit_id"=>"2", "level_id"=>"6"}` this seems interesting... aren't there supposed to be only 5 levels? Not 6? check all of your "+1"ing and check you don't have a fencepost error somewhere.

Comment: That is interesting. Every new habit represents 5 new level_id's so habit 1 = 1 - 5 level_id's, habit 2 = 6 - 10, habit 3 = 11 -15, etc. Don't see an error. I thinking maybe it's the AJAX @TarynEast?

Comment: right so "when I click a checkbox I expect to see XXX in the parameters" -> can you please fill in XXX ?

Comment: and I ask because you're talking a bit about "missed days" but haven't explained where they actually come in yet (how do they relate to habits and levels - should I expect to see "missed_days => 2" in the params? etc)

Comment: Yea @TarynEast each checkbox in a level (three checkboxes per level) represents a different `missed_day` so if one box is checked `missed_days => 1` if two are checked `missed_days => 2` if three are checked `missed_days => 3`. This same logic would occur for all 5 levels. So it should probably look like this: `Parameters: {"habit_id"=>"16", "level_id"=>"4", "missed_days" => "2"}` Do you think level_id will work properly if it continue to go up past 5? And overall I can't see why `missed_days` aren't showing when the routes look right. Added above :)

Comment: Your missed-days probably aren't showing up because your checkboxes don't actually have a name or id. They have "nil" instead... try: `<%= check_box_tag "missed_days_1", true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>` or similar... with the second and third being 2 and 3... remember, a checkbox will not give you `missed_days => 1` it will give you `:missed_days_1 => true` if you really want `:missed_days =>1` then you need radio buttons... but you still need to give them a name of `:missed_days`

Comment: Ahh I see. Well Each checkbox should be the same value since it is a checkbox not a radio button like you pointed out so if a person for some reason checks `[X] [   ] [X]` it would show `missed_days => 2` regardless of which two boxes are checked in the level. Is there a way we can make clicking a checkbox = 1 as I attempted in the days_missed controller @TarynEast?

Comment: converting this stuff to an "answer" as I think we've nailed down where the issue s... just arguing over semantics,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altered model and controller.

the **habits.rb** model

```
    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days #Added this line here.
```

I fixed up the controller, which is where I got level `missed_days` to equal habit `missed_days`:

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

def create
  habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
  habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
  habit.save!
  level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
  level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
  level.save!
  head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
end

def destroy
  habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
  habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
  habit.save
  level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
  level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
  level.save!
  head :ok # this returns an empty response with a 200 success status code
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missed-days probably aren't showing up because your checkboxes don't actually have a name or id. They have "nil" instead... try:

```
<%= check_box_tag "missed_days_1", true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
```

or similar... with the second and third being 2 and 3... remember, a checkbox will not give you `missed_days => 1` it will give you `:missed_days_1 => true` if you really want `:missed_days =>1` then you need radio buttons... but you still need to give them a name of `:missed_days`

> "Is there a way we can make clicking a checkbox = 1 as I attempted in
>   the days_missed controller"

Perhaps - you can set the value that a checkbox returns when checked... [check_box_tag doco](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) you pass that in the second param (instead of `true`). But the problem is that you have multiple checkboxes and if your checkboxes are named the same thing, they will overwrite each other and only the value of the last set will get returned.

Try naming them something like this: and see what the results are that you get back. Then work on the code you need to decipher what that means and put the right values in the right places after that.

```
<% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "missed_days[#{level}][1]", true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %> 
  <%= check_box_tag "missed_days[#{level}][2]", true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %> 
  <%= check_box_tag "missed_days[#{level}][3]", true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
<% end %>
```

Given rails' defaults... it is possible that the first one of these will *still* get converted to "true"... (you will need to check the return-value yourself to determine if this is the case)

Comment: Hey thank you Taryn. When I check the console it still is `missed_days: 0` despite what I check. I tried both your methods and then some :/ I don't see where I can find true or false via the return-value? In the console and via the AJAX post the code in the terminal all looks the same as before.

Comment: Ok, then we need to go back to my original idea of naming each check-box differently... i think what is happening is that the very last one will overwrite all of the other values. (ie ruby just keeps going `params[:missed_days] = <last checkbox value>` each checkbox needs to be named differently and you will need to figure out which ones are true or not. I'll change the checkboxes above, then you will have a look at the params that get returned from that and determine what you can do with that.

Comment: Played around with your code but now I'm just more confused :/ I updated your question with what the output is. Thank you so much for your time! I know I'm asking a lot here I've been at variations of this problem for months!

Comment: Sorry I'm confused - where is the output in the server logs that you got when you ran with the checkboxes I've given above? (note: you will need to add the other fields too... I've *only* included the checkboxes here because I don't want to repeat unnecessary stuff I don't mean you should remove the other code). The only thing you should change in your template is the name of the checkboxes to the above.

Comment: Ah I see - your attempt at editing my answer was rejected... that's because your results should go in your question, not in my answer. Regardless - the broken results you got (with no level) are because you literally interpreted my changes rather than just changing the checkbox names...

Comment: Sorry Taryn I'll know for the future to add the code to the question instead of editing the answer. I think I finally solved this dilemma. I kept playing around with your answer but I must have been missing something. Below is the answer to how I got this to work. Thank you so much for your help on this!